# Storing media resources in xml file

Tags: resources, media-player

I am working with a application where I want to play a mp3-file. Depending on a user choice (this part is finished) a specific file shall be played.
My intention is to use a specific Activity to play the file. To do this I need to read the identifier of the mp3 file from e.g. string.xml.
Is it possible to store the resource ID in an xml file? If it is the case, how? Or is there perhaps other solutions.

/Christer
New in Android development.

Answer (score 0):

This is now soleved:
The file name (without ext) is stored in a string-array and then use a code like this:

```
                Resources res = getResources();
                files=res.getStringArray(R.array.mp3_array);
                file=files[position];
                id=res.getIdentifier( file , "raw" , "packagename" );
```